# Nested Array Object Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

**Filter Nested Array Object with duplicate id**

Having different members with nested mailOpens Array of Objects.

***Have to solve this query:***
**The list of users who have >3 distinct mailOpens.mailingId records**

```
{
  "_index": "members",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "1234567",
  "_score": 2,
  "_source": {
    "mailOpens": [
      {
        "created": "04/26/2017",
        "mailingId": 1
      },
      {
        "created": "04/26/2017",
        "mailingId": 1
      },
      {
        "created": "07/14/2017",
        "mailingId": 2
      },
      {
        "created": "07/14/2017",
        "mailingId": 2
      },
      {
        "created": "07/14/2017",
        "mailingId": 3
      },
      {
        "created": "07/14/2017",
        "mailingId": 3
      },
      {
        "created": "07/14/2017",
        "mailingId": 4
      },
      {
        "created": "07/14/2017",
        "mailingId": 4
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Output should be like this for all members index with distinct mailingId:

```
{
  "_index": "members",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "1234567",
  "_score": 2,
  "_source": {
    "mailOpens": [
      {
        "created": "04/26/2017",
        "mailingId": 1
      },
      {
        "created": "07/14/2017",
        "mailingId": 2
      },
      {
        "created": "07/14/2017",
        "mailingId": 3
      },
      {
        "created": "07/14/2017",
        "mailingId": 4
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that ElasticSearch does not have this functionality.

From your expected response , what you are trying to do is to filter the results of an array from a specific document rather than to filter across the cluster. I think you need to do this at your end after you receive the response from Elastic. Preferably , you should probably remove this duplication at index time instead.

At most , what you can try is to an aggregation in order to get the count

```
GET test/doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "distint_count": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "mailOpens.mailingId"
      }
    }
  }
}




 "aggregations": {
    "distint_count": {
      "value": 4
    }
  }
}
```